# generating random sudoku puzzles in javascript results in unsolvable boards

Tags: javascript, generator, sudoku

im trying to generate random sudoku puzzles that can be solved, but am having trouble. i am able to create a 9x9 two-dimensional array with values, but oftentimes, the values have repeated in their own row. how can I prevent this from happening? below is my function which should return a sudoku board with emptied spots to solve.

```
    function pattern (r, c, base, side) { return (base * (r % base) + Math.floor(r / base) + c) % side; }
    function shuffle (s) { return s.sort(function () { return Math.random() - 0.5; }); }

    function getGrid () {

            var X = 0;

            var base = 3;
            var side = base * base;
            var rows = [], columns = [], numbers = [], b = [], newB = [];

            for (var x = 0; x < base; x++) {

                for (var y = 0; y < base; y++) {

                    rows.push(X * base + y);
                    columns.push(x * base + y);

                }

            }

            rows = shuffle(rows);
            columns = shuffle(columns);

            for (var n = 1; n < base * base + 1; n++) { numbers.push(n); }

            numbers = shuffle(numbers);

            for (var r = 0; r < rows.length; r++) {

                for (var c = 0; c < columns.length; c++) {

                    b.push(numbers[pattern(rows[r], columns[c], base, side)]);

                }

            }

            while (b.length) { newB.push(b.splice(0, 9)); }

            console.log(newB); // before removing some items, complete puzzle

            var squares = side * side;

            var emptySpots = Math.floor((squares * 3) / 4);

            for (var cell = 0; cell < squares; cell++) {

                if (Math.random() < 0.4) { newB[Math.floor(cell / side)][cell % side] = X; }

            }

            console.log(newB); // after removing some items, unsolved puzzle
            
            return newB;
            
    }
```

here is an example of an output which i have recieved from this function:

```
0: (9) [6, 3, 7, 0, 1, 5, 2, 8, 9]
1: (9) [7, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 4, 8]
2: (9) [6, 3, 7, 4, 1, 0, 2, 8, 9]
3: (9) [6, 0, 0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 8, 0]
4: (9) [7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 0, 8]
5: (9) [0, 5, 0, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4]
6: (9) [7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 4, 8]
7: (9) [0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 4]
8: (9) [0, 5, 6, 8, 3, 0, 7, 9, 4]
```

this isn't a solvable sudoku board, as there are values repeated in the same row/column/square. does anyone have any ideas?

```js
getGrid();

function pattern (r, c, base, side) { return (base * (r % base) + Math.floor(r / base) + c) % side; }
function shuffle (s) { return s.sort(function () { return Math.random() - 0.5; }); }

function getGrid () {

        var X = 0;

        var base = 3;
        var side = base * base;
        var rows = [], columns = [], numbers = [], b = [], newB = [];

        for (var x = 0; x < base; x++) {

            for (var y = 0; y < base; y++) {

                rows.push(X * base + y);
                columns.push(x * base + y);

            }

        }

        rows = shuffle(rows);
        columns = shuffle(columns);

        for (var n = 1; n < base * base + 1; n++) { numbers.push(n); }

        numbers = shuffle(numbers);

        for (var r = 0; r < rows.length; r++) {

            for (var c = 0; c < columns.length; c++) {

                b.push(numbers[pattern(rows[r], columns[c], base, side)]);

            }

        }

        while (b.length) { newB.push(b.splice(0, 9)); }

        console.log(newB); // before removing some items, complete puzzle

        var squares = side * side;

        var emptySpots = Math.floor((squares * 3) / 4);

        for (var cell = 0; cell < squares; cell++) {

            if (Math.random() < 0.4) { newB[Math.floor(cell / side)][cell % side] = X; }

        }

        console.log(newB); // after removing some items, unsolved puzzle
        
        return newB;
        
}
```

---

EDIT: i made the same program in python which worked perfectly, and i attempted to rewrite the same function in javascript, but the results are different. here is the working version in python:

```
def get_board():

    global _board
    global empty
    
    base  = 3
    side  = base * base

    def pattern(r, c): return (base * (r % base) + r // base + c) % side

    def shuffle(s): return sample(s, len(s)) 

    rows  = [g * base + row for g in shuffle(range(base)) for row in shuffle(range(base))] 
    columns  = [g * base + column for g in shuffle(range(base)) for column in shuffle(range(base))]

    numbers  = shuffle(range(1, base * base + 1))

    _board = [[numbers[pattern(r, c)] for c in columns] for r in rows]

    squares = side * side
    empties = squares * 3 // 4
    for p in sample(range(squares), empties): _board[p // side][p % side] = empty
```

could someone tell me how the algorithms differ?

Comment: It's kind of like the [N queens problem](https://medium.com/@jasondotparse/solving-the-n-queens-problem-with-javascript-207411967179), in that certain squares in a grid cannot be occupied because of certain squares in tangent to other squares that are occupied.

Comment: In the example, it goes from 0 to 9, but it should go from 1 to 9. I had to review my answer and algorithm. I think it would be great to edit it, to avoid some confusion.

Comment: I've never studied it, but I'm pretty sure the math needed to generate a random sudoku puzzle would include incredibly complex calculus requiring 1000's of lines of code, and not just a single function.

Answer (score 0):

I made one just for fun (before the Python algorithm, because I didn't know the restriction), unoptimised with the first algorithm that came to mind.

```js
const getColumn = (colNumber, lines) =>
{
    const col = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i)
    {
        const line = lines[i];
        col.push(line[colNumber]);
    }
    return col;
};

const getAllowed = (column, picks) =>
{
    const choosable = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < picks.length; ++i)
    {
        const pick = picks[i];
        if (!column.includes(pick))
        {
            choosable.push(pick);
        }
    }
    return choosable;
};

function getSquare(colNumber, lineNumber, lines)
{
    const detected = [];
    if (!lineNumber)
    {
        return detected;
    }

    let startCol = Math.floor(colNumber / 3) * 3;
    let endCol = startCol + 3;

    let startLine = Math.floor(lineNumber / 3) * 3;
    let endLine = Math.min(startLine + 3, lines.length);

    for (let i = startCol; i < endCol; ++i)
    {
        for (let j = startLine; j < endLine; ++j)
        {
            const item = lines[j][i];
            if (item !== undefined)
            {
                detected.push(item);
            }
        }
    }

    return detected;
}

const generateRandomLine = (lines) =>
{
    const line = [];
    let selectables = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    {
        const column = getColumn(i, lines);

        let allowed;

        // Remove column items
        allowed = getAllowed(column, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);

        // Remove line items
        allowed = getAllowed(line, allowed);

        // remove square items
        const square = getSquare(i, lines.length, lines);
        allowed = getAllowed(square, allowed);

        const random = allowed.length > 1 ? Math.floor(Math.random() * allowed.length) : 0;

        const chosen = allowed[random];
        if (chosen === undefined)
        {
            return false;
        }
        line.push(chosen);

        selectables.splice(selectables.indexOf(chosen), 1);
    }

    return line;
};

const generateGrid = () =>
{
    let iterations;
    do
    {
        const grid = [];
        iterations = 0;
        do
        {
            ++iterations;
            if (iterations > 500)
            {
                iterations = -1;
                // Invalid
                break;
            }

            const line = generateRandomLine(grid);
            if (!line)
            {
                continue;
            }
            grid.push(line);


        } while (grid.length < 9);

        if (iterations !== -1)
        {
            return grid;
        }

    } while (true);

};

const displayGrid = () =>
{
    const grid = generateGrid();

    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; ++i)
    {
        const line = grid[i];
        console.log(JSON.stringify(line));
    }
};

displayGrid();
```

PS: ~ 2h:10min

EDIT 1: Recheck Sudoku rules

EDIT 2: Hack & bug

Comment: The question was _how can I prevent values from repeating in the same row/column/square?_  While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Yes, of course. I took a shortcut because no Python code was given when I started generating this code. Had there been a Python tag, I would have avoided the question, not being the best at it. The Sudoku game requires different numbers in columns, lines and squares (3x3), which should be counted from 1 to 9. From 0 to 9, like in OP's example, you will always obtain unsolvable boards (which I did point out in a comment). So, investigating OP's code could have been time-consuming. My answer was only for those needing a quick solution while waiting for more responses.

Comment: Also, the question is precisely "Generating random sudoku puzzles in javascript results in unsolvable boards". I believe it was a slightly more open question which should not limit problem solvers to diverse approaches.

Answer (score 0):

seem this answer can solve your question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76596381/2674707

that is I did and seem work very well , so I'am share my idea

### build  complete Sudoku

you can generate one place (like middle center one) with random 1-9 on complete blank matrix, look like this :

```
   ·  ·  ·   ·  ·  ·   ·  .  ·
   ·  .  ·   ·  .  .   .  ·  .
   .  ·  ·   .  ·  ·   ·  ·  .

   ·  .  ·   2  9  1   .  ·  .
   ·  .  ·   8  6  7   ·  ·  ·
   ·  ·  ·   3  5  4   ·  ·  ·

   ·  ·  .   ·  .  ·   .  ·  ·
   ·  ·  .   ·  ·  .   .  ·  .
   ·  .  ·   ·  ·  ·   ·  ·  ·
```

so you can use **backtrace** solve and make complete sudoku

### random "dig hole" , after each "dig hole" you need verify this puzzle is one-solution

based on the complete sudoku , you can clear number of random position at it , that I'am call it "dig hole"  , after each dig hole , you need to verify the puzzle and make sure is one-solution, until all dig hole done

> how can verify a sudoku puzzle is one-solution ?
>
> use dfs try to find many solution, if only one, that mean one-solution, else you can break and return

### the "dig hold" count is your sudoku puzzle difficulty

in my project , four level difficulty : easy(40) / medium(45) / hard(50) / expert(56)

### references

I'am write sudoku **solver** and **generator** lib with different languages, maybe you can refer to it：

- [sudoku-nodejs](https://github.com/einsitang/sudoku-nodejs)
- [sudoku-go](https://github.com/einsitang/sudoku-go)
- [sudoku-dart](https://github.com/einsitang/sudoku-dart)
- [sudoku-flutter](https://github.com/einsitang/sudoku-flutter)

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. **Can you [edit] your answer to summarize the relevant guidance from the link?** Answers on Stack Overflow can certainly link to additional information, but they should stand on their own even if the page they are linking to is later (re)moved. This is important because often, over time, the linked pages are no longer available, which is frustrating for future members of the community.