# Different sudoku game levels in the same qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml, sudoku

How can I make a Sudoku game in c++ with 5 diffrent game levels but in the same qml file? What is the easiest way to do it? How can I modify my code in this scope?

I've made a sudoku grid in c++ and I pass it to qml using QAbstractTableModel and TableView.

This is the TableView:

```
TableView {
                anchors.fill: parent
                columnSpacing: 1
                rowSpacing: 1
                clip: true

                model: SudokuGrid {}

                delegate: Rectangle {
                    implicitWidth: 50
                    implicitHeight: 50
                    border {
                         color: "white"
                         width: 1
                    }
                    color: model.row % 2 ? "lightpink" : "lightblue"
                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: display
                        font.pointSize: 12
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is the c++ code:

```
    #include "Grid.h"

Grid::Grid(QObject *parent) : QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 9; ++col) {
            gridData[row][col] = (row * 3 + row / 3 + col) % 9 + 1;
        }
    }
}

int Grid::rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const
{
    return 9;
}

int Grid::columnCount(const QModelIndex &) const
{
    return 9;
}

QVariant Grid::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    switch (role) {
    case Qt::DisplayRole:
        return gridData[index.row()][index.column()];
    default:
        break;
    }

    return QVariant();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> Grid::roleNames() const
{
    return { {Qt::DisplayRole, "display"} };
}
```

And it's header:

```
    #pragma once

#include <QAbstractTableModel>

class Grid : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Grid(QObject *parent = nullptr);

public:
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & = QModelIndex()) const override;

    int columnCount(const QModelIndex & = QModelIndex()) const override;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;

signals:

private:
    int gridData[9][9];
};
```

Comment: If you have a way to generate sudoku grids and what you need is regenerate a new grid when the difficulty is changed, then how about you add a `difficulty` property to your model, bind it to the value of a control in QML and make it so that when it is changed, your model is reset with a new grid corresponding to the nex difficulty? Unrelated but it seems your `data` method never returns a null variant to represent the empty cells from the game start.

Comment: As already commented on your [very similar deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77814437/display-sudoku-grid-differently-using-combo-box-qml), please try to limit the scope of your question as much as possible. Please always edit your question, instead of deleting the old one and creating a new very similar question.

Comment: It seems to me that the essential part of your task is how to generate a sudoku of a certain difficulty independent of the programming language you want to use (qml / C++). If you don't know how to do it, it may be better to edit your question to focus on that first and remove all irrelevant code from your question (especially all the qml code and even most of the C++ code, like the QAbstractItemModel sugar).

Comment: Related question: [How to generate Sudoku boards with unique solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924216/how-to-generate-sudoku-boards-with-unique-solutions)

Comment: Searching for "generating sudoku" using your favorite search engine, may be useful too.

Comment: Can you actually generate sudoku for just 1 difficultty level? Start with that. Then add a compile time constant for the difficulty level, and make that work right (change and recompile to get different difficulty). Then add UI for changing it at runtime.