# Generation of sudoku questions

Tags: algorithm, sudoku

I am doing a sudoku game. My problem is the generation of sudoku questions. I want to generate  questions in three difficulties. Is there any idea to generate 3 level questions?

Comment: This would seem more apt for game development.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating sudoku initial boards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218223/creating-sudoku-initial-boards)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we go for pre generated sudoku puzzles, maybe you could have a look at this :
http://www.setbb.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?t=102&mforum=sudoku

we used terminal sudoku in the Linux distributions

it has a batch generator mode.
the website is down but it is packaged for some linux distributions.

generate  puzzles for each level : easy, medium and hard

```
sudoku -fcompact -ceasy -g5>sudoku_easy.txt
sudoku -fcompact -cmedium -g5>sudoku_medium.txt
sudoku -fcompact -chard -g5>sudoku_hard.txt
```

solve the puzzles

```
sudoku -fcompact -v sudoku_easy.txt >sudoku_easy-resolved.txt
sudoku -fcompact -v sudoku_medium.txt >sudoku_medium-resolved.txt
sudoku -fcompact -v sudoku_hard.txt >sudoku_hard-resolved.txt
```

I checked some of them and they had only one solution.

Answer (score 1):

Generate full (filled) sudokus and before printing the sudoku out, make some percentage of the fields empty again for the human to fill.

Select random fields to empty. Raise the percentage of empty fields on each difficulty level.

Comment: @DanielFischer might not even be necessary. The original sudoku makes sure there is at least one solution. The human filled solution can then be checked separately.

Comment: But you need uniqueness, otherwise it's pointless. And uniqueness is easily lost when removing hints.

Comment: @DanielFischer why is uniqueness required? you can just compute the user's solution and see all their values are correct or not

Comment: If there's more than one solution, it's not a logical puzzle anymore. The point is that the solution shall be found by deduction, not by trial and error. If it's not unique, that is impossible.

Comment: @DanielFischer "Find solutions to this sudoku" ;)

Comment: Any serious Sudoku solver will hate it if it's not unique. (by definition;)